# Jest/enzyme can't find checked attribute on input checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing a test for this component.

```
    <div>
      <label className='switch me-4' htmlFor={`checkbox-${props.idx}`}>
        <input id={`checkbox-${props.idx}`} type="checkbox" defaultChecked={props.defaultChecked} onChange={props.onChange} />
        <span className='slider round'></span>
      </label>
      {props.label}
    </div>
```

I want to assert that the `checked` attribute is present when passing in the prop `defaultChecked={true}` as this is the case in the actual browser.

```
let onChange: jest.Mock<any, any>;

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();

  onChange = jest.fn();
});

test('Renders true.', () => {
  const component = shallow(<ToggleSwitch
    onChange={onChange}
    idx={1}
    defaultChecked={true}
  />);

  let toggled = component.find({ type: 'checkbox' });
  expect(toggled).toBeChecked()
})
```

I've also tried `expect(toggled.props().checked).toEqual(true)`.

The problem seems to be that the `checked` attribute does not exist in the props but everything I've read indicates that it should be there. See the props below.

```
    {
      id: 'checkbox-1',
      type: 'checkbox',
      defaultChecked: true,
      onChange: [Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }
```

Thanks!